# Is it wrong to use Image Picker in Flutter for .png file?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

Using image_picker to select png files logs an error but the app works fine(the png file gets selected). The error i get

> image_picker only supports compression for jpg files

I want to use it for .png files. Can I still use it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using file_picker package, https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker,(with filter, type: FileType.IMAGE) instead of image_picker package works with .png without logging an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using the [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) plugin would be the best option for this. It is a well developed plugin and easily implemented.

Here is an example implementation that you could use for PNG files only.

```
  List<File> _paths;

  FileType _pickingType;

  bool _hasVailMime;

  Future<List<File>> _openImageFileExplorer() async {

    if(_pickingType != FileType.CUSTOM || _hasValidMime){
      try {
        _paths = await FilePicker.getMultiFile(   // Or getFile
            type: FileType.CUSTOM, fileExtension: 'png');
      }
      on PlatformException catch (e){
        print("Unsupported operation: " + e.toString());
      }
    }
    return _paths;
  }
```